# Matrix transformation in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

can anybody help me with a problem regarding transforming a matrix in python...
suppose I have a matrix

```
x = [a b c;
     d e f]
```

and I want to get a matrix like

```
xx = [a b c 0 0 0
      a b c 0 0 0
      0 0 0 d e f
      0 0 0 d e f]
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: actually I am implementing it in python...

Comment: Could you see the matrix properly? As I was not able to see the matrix, I now I written it in this form... Another thing is can there be an easy way out to get the matrix using numpy kron?

Comment: Did you try `numpy` packge?

Answer (score 2):

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = np.zeros([2,3])
c = np.concatenate([[a,b],[b,a]])
```

Comment: Many thanks for the solution... But I want to make it automated because I do have a big matrix of order suppose 12 X 33. Can you make this process automated?

Comment: assuming your matrix is size (nxm) 

a = np.array(m List of n List) # you can create this right?

b = np.zeros([n, m]) # only dimension change

c = np. concatenate([[a, b], [a, b]]) # this line is identical